# JSP filter the illegal url direct access

Tags: java, jsp, web

Has JSP filter setting can deny the direct URL access?

I means that accept all page links to another page, 
but when you're direct access the page, it's denied.

Like that when I entry to this page by previous page, it's allow:

> edit.jsp?id=99

But I change the id

> edit.jsp?id=100

it's illegal , because of direct access

I'm not using the framework struts2.Just simple JSP code.

thanks

Comment: How you are manage your autorization, roles ?, or just valid users ?

Comment: there are roles, like general user,advanced user,manager.
most pages can filter the roles , 
but when meet the edit pages like edit.jsp?id=100
I don't know is there some good way to denied user change the parameter.

I don't want to check all pages that has parameter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop an user to type that and hit.

Write a `Servlet Filter` and map all your jsp page  which needs `authentication`, before processing the request.

There in the filter check weather user is authorized to view it or not.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13718/servlet.htm